# $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x|+|y|^{1/2}<1\}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

How to prove that $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x|+|y|^{1/2}<1\}$ is convex? I tried using the definition but couldn’t go far, since the second component involves square root(tried squaring, that made it complicated).

I plotted it in mathematica and the graph comes out to be convex, but how to prove it mathematically?

I started with two points (x,y) and (a,b) in A, and tried to prove (ta+(1-t)x, tb +(1-t)y) is in A, for which I need to show, $| ta+(1-t)x|+|t b +(1-t)y|^{1/2}<1$, but since the square root term is there, I couldn’t simplify this.

Comment: What is the definition of convex? What parts of the proof do you have, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Convexity for me is, the line segment joining two points lie within the domain( geometric convexity).

Comment: Great! Include this in the post, and the first parts of the proof to get the best response (since this indicates that you do understand quite a bit!!)

Comment: It's not convex. Take $(0.9, 0)$ and $(0, 0.9)$ in the set, but the midpoint is not in the set.

Comment: @Theo Bendit, it is not convex, thanks for pointing out. I was going in wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easily seen [graphically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hvwbfhhlav) that this set is not convex.

Answer (score 3):

It's not convex :
[[image: Surface <span class=]$\{|x| + \sqrt{|y|} < 1\}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqRPa.png)